# AttributeError at /callback/ module 'zeep.client' has no attribute 'service'

Tags: python, django, zeep

when I want to use the zeep package in django for the payment gateway, I face an error.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOvsv.jpg),
[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua7AQ.jpg)

callback function in views.py in shop app:

```
# Callback function
def callback(request):
    if request.GET.get('Status') == 'NOK':
        authority = request.GET.get('authority')
        invoice = get_object_or_404(models.Invoice, authority=authority)
        amount = 0
        order = invoice.order
        order_items = models.OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)
        for item in order_items:
            amount += item.product_cost
        result = client.service.PaymentVerification(MERCHANT, authority, amount)
        if result.Status == 100:
            return render(request, 'callback.html', {'invoice': invoice})
        else:
            return HttpResponse('error ' + str(result.Status))
    else:
        return HttpResponse('error ')
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `client`?

Comment: @dgw Unfortunately, I didn't understand what you meant, but anyway, when I use this code `result = client.service.PaymentVerification(MERCHANT, authority, amount)` I face this problem and says module 'zeep.client' has no attribute 'service'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zeep documentation shows that the object `client` must be initialized as shown in the example listed on the site:

```
from zeep import Client, Settings

settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
client = Client('http://my-wsdl/wsdl', settings=settings)
```

I suspect you either made a typo in defining it or just never did.

Comment: And what would that error message be? Perhaps something to do with not having zeep installed? In that case you should run `pip install zeep` in the command-line if you're running on windows. Refer to the documentation for further support and mark my reply as the answer since the original question has been answered by it.

Comment: You were right, I had not initialized the client, but now I did it and faced the error.
Error summary:
File "C:\Users\Hamed\Desktop\All\AllProject\Programing\Python\django_shop\django_env\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://sandbox.banktest.ir/zarinpal/www.zarinpal.com/pg/StartPay/

Comment: Images links:
https://postimg.cc/gallery/0q59SGF

Comment: Sadly I have no idea why your url could be unavailible, you're on your own for this one.

Comment: I have already installed the zeep package in both public and virtual environments Thanks.